# Trouble with quadratic integration

Tags: integration

I'm practising integration and seem to have run into one specific kind of problem which i can't seem to fix. I'm hoping someone could tell me where i went wrong.

The problem is $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{7-6x-x^2}}$. I manage to solve it by changing the problem into the form $\dfrac{1}{a[(x+b/2a)^2 + (c/a - b^2/4a^2)]}$ and the answer is almost right. The correct answer is $\arcsin[(x+3)/4]$ . Almost because there is the $\sqrt{-1}$ in my answer yet it is not present in the textbook's answer. How was ${i}$ eliminated?

Comment: Your $a$ should be $-1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$7-6x-x^2=4^2-(x+3)^2,x+3=4\sin\theta\implies dx=4\cos\theta\ d\theta$$

$$\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{7-6x-x^2}}=\text{sign of}(\cos\theta)\int\frac{4\cos\theta\ d\theta}{4\cos\theta}=\text{sign of}(\cos\theta)\cdot\theta+K$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{7-6x-x^2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{16-x^2-6x-9}}=$$
$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4^2-(x^2+2x\cdot3}+3^2)}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4^2-(x+3)^2}}=$$
$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4^2(1-(\frac{x+3}{2})^2}}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{(1-(\frac{x+3}{2})^2}}=$$
$$\frac{x+3}{2}=\sin t,dx/2=\cos tdt$$